# Very simple javascript doesn't work at all

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

My JavaScript in .php (static website) file doesn't work. I use there 3 other scripts and they do work, but not this one.

The situation is simple

The JavaScript is:

```
var myFile = document.getElementById('myFile');

myFile.addEventListener('change', function() {

  alert(this.files[0].size); 
});
```

and the HTML code in the PHP file is (stripped):

```
<form onsubmit="return anotherfunction();" action="sendForm.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">    
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Attach an image:</td>
        <td> <input type="file" name="priloha[]" accept="image/*" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

And the JavaScript does nothing, it acts like it doesn't exist. I tried to use the JS in the header, below the header, in the body, in the TD of the input... I also tried using it in external .js file, nothing, doesn't work at all. I tried changing "change" to "click", didn't work neither. I tried to do this all day and I can't figure out what's wrong.

So I tried to do much simpler code to check what's wrong and it seems like `change` or `onchange` - the second line of the JS doesn't work.

I also tried to specify HTML5 doctype, doesn't do a thing.

My extra .html file to try even simpler code looks like this and of course doesn't work...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>      
  </head> 
  <body>
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td>Input field for click popup:</td>
            <td>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                var input = document.getElementById('input');
                input.addEventListener('click', function() {
                alert("Hello"); 
                });
                </script>
            <input type="text" id="input" />
            
            </td>
        </tr>
    <table>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Help me please, I don't really know what's this...
I forgot to mention, I tried different browsers - Opera 12.15, latest Firefox and Chrome, didn't work in any case. But it works in fiddle...

Comment: Where is the fiddle? Can you post it here?

Comment: You need to run the JavaScript **after** the element is ready/rendered. Whether that means inside of `window.onload = function () { };` or just sometime literally after the input's HTML. Otherwise, the `document.getElementById()` won't be able to find the element.

Comment: this works in chrome for me: http://jsfiddle.net/GHzp5/

Comment: in your first few lines, you mention `document.getElementById('myFile')`, but have no elements with id=myFile in your HTMl. later on you've got matched ids, so ... possible problem?

Comment: @Jason You have the JavaScript set to run `onLoad`, so of course that works

Comment: Fiddle's here http://jsfiddle.net/6ZQkj/267/ . I try to run in after, I'm not sure if I tried yet - why some scripts are supposed to be in the header, some in the body and some in front of </body> tag?

Comment: Have a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9657629/218196) (especially the example at the end) which explains a bit why you have to put certain code at different locations.

Comment: @TeeJay your fiddle seems to work. However, you are not supposed to use the same Id more than once...and you do that a lot.

Comment: You were right Ian, thank you... oh my god, why couldn't I get to know this myself, so much wasted hours... but you made my day in the end, thank you, I will have a nice sleep. Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks Felix, I'll read it twice to be sure that I remember everything.

Comment: @basilikum I know that well, I was so upset that I did such stupid mistake, but I found out soon after re-reading the code. Just didn't know how to update fiddle code :o)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put the script right at the end of the body, right before the `</body>` end tag.

Scripts are loaded synchronously where they are placed, so any script put in *before* the element in question will not be aware of the element's existence.

Also, what Igor said.

Comment: Thank you very much :) also for the explanation, that's what I needed, I need to comprehend things to use them properly. Thanks once more.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a DOM element with id "myFile" in html that you included.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I stripped it for the shorter code here , it's there actually.