# Why does my $(".selector").show(900); code only fire-up in the browser console, but never in the helper?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, show-hide

My `$(".submitNumberForm").show(900);` code in my **Template.home.helpers** fails to fire-up. However, when the code is run in the browser console, it works perfectly.

The fact that the `$(".submitNumberForm").show(900);` fails to run in the **Template.home.helpers** means that an **HTML form** represented by class name: `.submitNumberForm` is never shown and remains hidden.

I would be grateful if someone would kindly explain what is wrong with my code.

Find below my helper code: `../client/main.js`, pay special attention to the `$(".submitNumberForm").show(900);`.

```
Template.home.helpers({

    'displaySubmitForm': function () {

        var verificationCode = Meteor.user().profile.telephoneNumberVarificationCode;
        var verificationCodeTest = Meteor.user().profile.telephoneNumberVarified;

        if( typeof verificationCode === 'undefined' && typeof verificationCodeTest === 'undefined'){
                console.log("displaySubmitForm verificationCode: " +verificationCode);
                console.log("displaySubmitForm verificationCodeTest: " +verificationCodeTest);

                alert("displaySubmitForm: TRUE");

                $(".submitNumberForm").show(900);

                return true;
            }

        else {
                alert("displaySubmitForm: FALSE");

                $(".submitNumberForm").hide(900);

                return false;
            }
    }

});
```

When the `home` page is refreshed, the browser console prints out:

```
displaySubmitForm verificationCode: undefined
displaySubmitForm verificationCodeTest: undefined
```

and the alert function displays a popup displaying: `displaySubmitForm: TRUE`, however the `$(".submitNumberForm").show(900);` doesn't fire-up!

Find below my: `<template name="home">` code `../client/main.html`. Note that The `{{displaySubmitForm}}` at the top/begining of the template, displays the words `true`, however the rest of the **HTML form** `submitNumberForm` doesn't display at all. This, again is an indication that the `$(".submitNumberForm").show(900);` code doesn't fire-up

```
<template name="home">
{{displaySubmitForm}}

    {{#if displaySubmitForm}}

        <div class="form-group submitNumberForm">

            <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="telephoneNumber" placeholder="Enter Number"  name="telephoneNumber">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="button" id="submitNumber" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    {{else}}

    {{/if}}

</template>
```

Find below my CSS file: `.../client/main.css`

```
.submitNumberForm{
    display: none; 
}
```

Just to clarify, the **html form** `submitNumberForm` is meant to be hidden by default and only show `$(".submitNumberForm").show(900);` based on the conditions specified in the `Template.home.helpers`

Again, when I copy code from the helper, paste and run in the console, the  **Html form** `submitNumberForm` appears. Can anyone kindly explain to me why this `$(".submitNumberForm").show(900);` doesn't fire-up in the helper as its supposed to do?

Comment: Is there a `document.ready` check in there? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657572/jquery-document-ready)

Comment: @cmbuckley thank you for your response. When using the Meteor framework, `document.ready` is not required. The meteor framework has built-in mechanisms that handles the `document.ready`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `{{#if displaySubmitForm}}` it means: Generate the html code between the `{{#if}}` and `{{/if}}` tags when the `displaySubmitForm helper` returns true.

The html elements inside your `if` doesn't exist when your helper is executing. 
So your selector: `$(".submitNumberForm")` in your code doesn't select anything, **because the submitNumberForm element doesn't exist yet**.

After that, it works on the console because the helper already executed and the html is now generated.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, that makes alot to sense actually. Now... how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Well it depends what's your purpose. I think your real question here is: _How to make elements appear in a fancy way in Meteor/BlazeJS ?_ Some ideas: Use CSS or package like: https://github.com/webtempest/meteor-animate. If you have trouble you should create a new topic because this one is not asking this question.